# Using static library in both App and Cocoa Touch Framework targets

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, google-analytics, frameworks, static-libraries

I've created a new "Cocoa Touch Framework" target called *MyAppCore* in my iPad project called *MyApp*, with the intention of putting some common code in there. Overall it works great, however, I've encountered problems with adding the static library provided by Google Analytics.

I want to be able to use Google Analytics not only in the *MyApp* target, but inside of the *MyAppCore* target as well. In order to make both targets build, I have to link both targets with libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a. That appears to work, but when I run the app, the log is bombarded with messages like these:

```
Class GAI is implemented in both /path/to/MyAppCore.framework/MyAppCore 
and /path/to/MyApp.app/MyApp.
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

How can I share Google Analytics between the two targets in a successful way?

Comment: you found any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by creating a wrapper class for Google Analytics (which is pretty handy to have, anyways) in the MyAppCore target. All access to Google Analytics will go through this wrapper. That way the only target that will use Google Analytics directly is MyAppCore, so I only have to link that target with Google Analytics.

This does not solve the underlying issue of sharing static libraries between my app target and a Cocoa Touch Framework, but for this purpose it works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your static library depends on the external static library, don't link against it.  Your main app will link against BOTH your library and the 3rd party library.  A static library is a bunch of built code so you have two copies of everything doing things the way you are doing now.

You should still be able to reference the headers for the 3rd party library and things should compile on your static library without any warnings.

In my application I have two static libraries.  "Wraith" is dependent on "PhilosophersStone" and the app is dependent on both.  (Target Dependencies in Build Phases)

"Wraith" does not link against "PhilosophersStone", main app links against both.  (Link Binary With Libraries in Build Phases)

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. This does not work in my case, likely because MyAppCore is not a static library (like Wraith in your example). MyAppCore is a dynamic framework, what XCode calls "Cocoa Touch Framework". Not a "Cocoa Touch Static Library".